# Netbeans build process seems to rebuild all Jars each time

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.7

We have a project consisting of several modules (Netbeans projects).
When i tell Netbeans to compile one of the files in the top level module, it starts to check all modules depended on and builds a jar for each one (at least that's what the log messages say twice every time).

I had done a full clean and build this morning and all the jars should be up to date except for the top level jar. But even though there aren't any files to compile for the other modules, this process will take about a minute per module. And to make matters worse central modules appear once for each time they are referenced by another module.

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to help Netbeans to focus on the changed sources?

It's Netbeans 6.7 and the netbeans.conf is already set to -Xmx512m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would upgrade to NB 6.8 and make sure that I used the Compile on save/deploy on save feature as much as possible for my projects.

If you are running into issues while using compile on save, [file issues with the NetBeans project](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) so they can get addressed.

Comment: Thank you, i think activating "compile on save" fixed it. At least it feels like i have no compiler delay at all. And i didn't have to upgrade - "compile on save" is available in Netbeans 6.5+.
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave